# Is the PY4G HVAC unit compatible with Nest Thermostat?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, air-conditioning, thermostat-c-wire, nest

I recently bought a Nest Thermostat and I've had nothing but trouble with it. The main symptom is the fan and the AC compressor won't run at the same time. Power only comes through the green wire, not the yellow. So I have been running AC with no fan just to make it through the hot summer days.

I think I have narrowed down my problems to not having a common wire connected. Luckily, I have an 18/5 bundle running to the thermostat so I was able to connect  the common wire. However, the nest reported no power to common ([E79](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9240096?hl=en#troubleshooting/e79)). I started to look into the HVAC unit manual and I ran across the following sentence.

> Do not use any type of power-stealing thermostat. Unit control
>   problems may result.

I know Nest thermostats can be power-stealing. Is this a show stopper for me? Do I need to revert back to a "dumb" thermostat?

For Reference...

- 3rd Gen Nest.
- HVAC Unit Model Number: PY4G 30060 ATP
- Link to the HVAC Install manual. Quote is on page 11, Control Voltage Connections: https://resource.carrierenterprise.com/is/content/Watscocom/payne_py4gnab24060--tp_article_1466843547903_en_ii

Comment: Can you measure 24VAC between R and C at the thermostat?

Comment: I'm getting  .3 between R and C and 27.5 between R and everything else...

Comment: Can you post photos of how the control junction box in your rooftop unit is wired, then?

Comment: Here is a link to a photo album https://imgur.com/a/s0tstVT with some images of the actual unit as well as a screen grab of figure 14 of the install manual.

Comment: Is there a wiring junction in the middle of your thermostat run? It seems like the cable at the package unit end is something like an 18/7 or 18/8, *not* an 18/5...

Comment: That was my first thought as well. I didn't see a junction when I checked the run yesterday. Maybe there's one before it gets to the crawlspace or after it enters the wall. I'll look a little more closely.

Comment: The orange/black/blue wires aren't just stuffed in the wall behind the T-stat? Do you get 24VAC between R and C at the wire nuts where they hook up to the thermostat wire? What about at the control board? What about off the transformer? I wonder if your old thermostat didn't care about DH but you need to hook the nest up to it? The blue wire looks like it's capped and stuffed behind all the other wire nuts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the PY4G unit is compatible with the Nest 3rd Gen Thermostat. I'm guessing that the quote from the manual about power-stealing is to ensure users use the common wire and don't rely on smart thermostats' power-stealing.

My issue was that I had 18/8 coming from the outdoor unit that met with 18/5, but only 4 wires {Y-G-W-R} were connected. The junction was hidden behind the aluminum flashing that protects the main duct before it enters the crawlspace. This is why I didn't see it when I was in my crawl.

I connected the blue wires, got a good reading on the multimeter, the Nest Thermostat no longer gives an error, and my HVAC is working again. Shoutout to @ThreePhaseEel for the help!